# How to add a CNAME for localhost in BIND 9?

Tags: bind, localhost, cname-record

I am doing web development and host the local versions of sites on my machine. I have Linux Slackware 14.0 with BIND 9.9.1-P3. In my named.conf I have this:

```
zone "localhost" IN {
    type master;
    file "caching-example/localhost.zone";
    allow-update { none; };
};
```

In localhost.zone:

```
$TTL    86400
$ORIGIN localhost.
@           1D IN SOA   @ root (
                    56      ; serial (d. adams)
                    3H      ; refresh
                    15M     ; retry
                    1W      ; expiry
                    1D )        ; minimum

            1D IN NS    @
            1D IN A     127.0.0.1
```

Suppose, I have a domain, called `dubai`, that I want to reference to localhost. I tried to add a CNAME record for localhost into localhost.zone:

```
dubai   IN  CNAME   localhost.
```

But it didn't work. How can I add a CNAME for localhost, so I could host multiple sites on my machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The zone file you're working in is for the reverse lookup zone of `0.0.127.in-addr.arpa`, you need to be working with a zone that can contain `dubai.` or `localhost.` to work with those records.

Seems like you really just want to be using your `/etc/hosts` file, not setting up a BIND service.

If you do want to use BIND, then you should create a forward lookup zone.  To use those names you can make a `zone "."`, but that will break resolution of actual internet names for systems pointed to this DNS server.  It'd probably be better to create something like `zone "dev.localhost"`, with a zone file along these lines:

```
@ IN A 127.0.0.1
dubai IN CNAME @
```

Comment: I updated the question for localhost.zone file. I tried to add CNAME, using your approach, but it didn't work.

Comment: @user4035 Have you restarted the service after making the change?  What's returned from `dig @localhost localhost any` and `dig @localhost dubai.localhost`?

Comment: Ahh, no it works! With exactly the same settings, I wrote in the question. Thx.

Comment: Here is the dig answer: ;; ANSWER SECTION:
dubai.                  86400   IN      A       127.0.0.1